# How do I get include dir for OpenSSL?

Tags: c, macos, openssl, header-files

After downloading openssl-1.0.2h from openssl.org/source I noticed the /include/ directory is empty. I assume I have to download the developer version zip for includes, or compile something??

I need to run https://github.com/torsten/keychain_access but it won't run on latest Mac OS since OpenSSL headers apparently were removed this version. And apparently the includes are removed from the tgz they distribute on openssl.org.

Comment: You have to configure and build it first.  Not familiar with building it on OSX though...

Comment: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1630

Comment: When I built my own openssl-1.0.2h for Mac last week, I set the install directory to `/opt/openssl-1.0.2h`, and the install created `/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/include/openssl` directory with a lot of OpenSSL headers in it.  I'm not sure whether that helps you or not.  I've not messed with using it in anguish (anger) yet, so I don't know whether there are problems still to deal with, but the compilation seemed to work OK for me.

Comment: If you compile and build from source then the includes are installed @ `/usr/local/ssl/include`

Comment: I thought it was already installed on Mac OS... just needs headers for compiling this small app?

Comment: @StianSkjelstad Yes I did `xcode-select --install` and compile is still not working.

Comment: @NoBugs: OpenSSL is installed (mind you an old version), but Apple no longer includes the headers for OpenSSL. You'll either have to compile/build/install it, or use Macports or Homebrew. You also need to disable SIPS before trying to install it, otherwise you will not be able to install/write anything to the req dirs.

Comment: @l'L'l Is it necessary to *install* it, not just build and grab header includes and link it in somehow when compiling keychain_access?

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily need to install it (eg. you could compile/build it and then just link against the libs it produces in the build directory). If you only want to use OpenSSL to build something and then remove it MacPorts is also convenient because you can simply uninstall it without hassle.

Comment: [Compilation and Installation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki